# Enter object with dsm

Tags: 7

i am actualy trying to read a field value in my panelized node.

I want to recieve the data in the red marked field, as u can see in my screenshot.

[image]

I tried to following:

```
<?php print_r($display->context['panelizer']['data']['field_centerpage_layout'][0]['value']); ?>
```

But I recieve this Error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type ctools_context as array in C:\seu\xampp\htdocs\iptp\sites\all\themes\mytheme\plugins\layouts\he_two_70_30\he-two-70-30.tpl.php on line 29

I would be thankful for any kind of help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your Krumo output (plus the very descriptive error message), `data` is an object, not an array. I'd imagine `$display->context['panelizer']` is also an object but it's hard to say as you haven't mentioned in your question how that's populated. You should use either

```
$display->context['panelizer']['data']->field_centerpage_layout[0]['value']
```

or

```
$display->context['panelizer']->data->field_centerpage_layout[0]['value']
```

Probably the second one.